Excel VBA .formula not working for cell object
!WARNING!
! im new to Excel and VBA so i mostly have no idea what im doing :( !
I want to make a script that goes through a selected range, and for every cell in that range, changes the formula to be a function that evaluates what the starting formula is numerically equal to
It seems like the .formula here should be working just fine, because the object i want to get the formula for is just a cell

Here's the code:
Sub Functions()
End Sub
    
    Function GetFormula(Target As Range) As String
        GetFormula = Target.Formula
    End Function
    
    Function Eval(Ref As String)
        Application.Volatile
        Eval = Evaluate(Ref)
    End Function

    


Sub FixFormat(gyaat As Ranges)

For Each c In Range(gyaat).Cells
    c.Formula = Eval(GetFormula(c.Adress))
    Next


End Sub
Sub bruh()
    
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        Dim myRange As Range
        Set myRange = Selection
        Dim myCells As Object
        
    Else
        MsgBox "Please select a Range", vbInformation
    End If
    
    For Each myCells In myRange
        myCells.Formula = Eval(GetFormula(myCells.Adress))
        Next
    

End Sub

any idea as how to fix this? or if im completely wrong, what should i do instead?
im thinking that the function is in any myCells cell might contain references to other cells, but i could make a separate macro script just for that
Thanks for your help!
I've opened like 20 tabs and googled the frick out of what the error is, this is where i got stuck in the debugging process (about 3 or 4 errors in)
I tried using a custom function to do it for me, but functions are really just for setting the value of the cell that uses them, so i don't think something like a function where you selected some cells and the value of the cells you selected gets changed really is a thing

Can you give an example of what you want to achieve?

First, correct spelling to Address (double d).

Why not something like myCells.Formula = "=" & myCells.Value ?  Please consider adding some basic example of "before" and "after" states for the type of cells you're working with.  Right now it's not very clear exactly what you want to achieve.

@TimWilliams
i tried that but for some reason VBA gives me a 1004 error "Application-defined or object-defined error". Adding in an "=" sign works everywhere except the beginning of a formula, though adding the "=" at the beginning in by hand for each cell works just fine. And the exact same code can add a "=" to an empty cell just fine, which is just weird

@user24712097
I suspect it has something to do with the "^" character some cells use, sometimes followed by a negative power, but i still don't know how to fix it

Seems like you found a solution, but since you didn't provide any specific examples for what you wanted to replace I'm not clear what the actual root of the problem was.

Your GetFormula function expects a range.
Function GetFormula(Target As Range) As String
    GetFormula = Target.Formula
End Function

But when you call it, you pass an address/a string:
c.Formula = Eval(GetFormula(c.Adress))

So, change this line to:
c.Formula = Eval(GetFormula(c))


Thank you for the help! This answer and the 3 comments i received really made all the difference!
